# Issue with custom control - Unknown property

Tags: custom-controls, xpages

I have a custom control with one property, showDeleteButton.

- Type: boolean
- Editor: Boolean value
- Required field: true

Sporadically I get this error message when building, in the XPages that use it:

**Unknown property showDeleteButton. It is not defined on tag xc:ccCommonActions**

I've tried deleting the custom control and recreating it. The issue still pops up after a few builds. I can work around the issue by disabling the required property, saving, enabling, saving, project->clean.

Have anyone encountered this issue/know what might be wrong?

Comment: It might be related to the issue described [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352550/meaning-of-java-lang-classcastexception-someclass-incompatible-with-someclass

Comment: Can you check xsp-config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've nailed the reason. I tested source control on the NSF a while back. Not sure if it's normal, but DDE created a subfolder in the VFS with the name I gave the project. I deleted the folder, and so far it looks like it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

I got these kind of errors too. It has something to do with build automatically turned off since 8.5.3. My solution: Cut the control out of the application, do a rebuild and project -> clean and then paste the control back in (and a rebuild and project -> clean).

Comment: Works temporarily, like toggling the required-attribute on the custom control/saving/rebuilding.

Comment: If the error is that a property isn't defined on you control it may be caused by 'old' compiled version of your control. You have probably 'double' class files of your control. I encountered the exact the same problem with java classes, it was driving me crazy! I had to completely cut everything related to Xpages, do a clean and rebuild and paste it back in. I finally found the cause of this problem by using Source Sniffer (on openntf). If you take a look at all the files it exports on your disk you'll see that it exports multiple of the same class files of your control.

Comment: I think I've nailed the reason. I tested source control on the NSF a while back. Not sure if it's normal, but DDE created a subfolder in the VFS with the name I gave the project. I deleted the folder yesterday, and so far it looks like it's ok. So there were double class files. Even though they were in different folders, it could be that they interfered with each other. If I don't get any more errors after a day or two, I'll put this down as resolved. :)

Answer (score 1):

add a default value to the property and try again. If auto build is off you need to build once to activate that.