# "Unknown property" error in Designer when using Object Data Source

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I occasionally have a build issue with custom controls that have a property that is an Object Data Source: after the build I get on error on any XPage using that property:

```
Unknown property XX. It is not defined on tag xc:customControlName
```

If I look in the Designer trace log (Help > Support > View Trace) I see a message saying:

```
Could not resolve the property-class for the property XX. Ignoring this property. The property-class specified was com.ibm.xsp.extlib.model.ObjectDataSource.
```

The ExtLib is installed in Designer as well as on the server.

Anyone seen this and knows how to solve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630187/issue-with-custom-control-unknown-property does this help?

Comment: Is the application missing the <faces-config-extension> file by any chance?  The file name *should* end in '-config'.  If present, check that the property is defined there properly. If missing, then locate or create file.

Comment: After a Designer restart I was able to build again. This issue appears every now and then. All apps I'm seeing it in are under source control, so I have a hunch that it's related to that. Frantisek: Read that question, but that was with booleans. I've checked the ODS repo, but didn't see a subdir. Steve: I'll check that if the issue appears again. Thanks both!

Comment: Mark, now that I think about it we are having similar problems here, but get a different error message. It seems that DDE forgets about the faces-config-extension file and gives an "unknown tag" error.  However, everything still works. Cleaning removes the error, but it comes back will future builds. We have just come to live with it, but it would be great to know how to make it go away for good.