# Resource is out of sync with the file system after ACL change

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

This appears to be a common error for java.  I searched for the error but could find nothing specific to domino and the ACL issue.

I have a couple of java classes in my database.  One is a HttpServlet class, the other an IHttpServlet factory.  I also added just a regular class to the db for testing.

Any time I make any change to the ACL, the servlet will no longer run.  If any of the java source document are open, it shows Resource is out of sync with the file system: mydb.nsf  Press F9 or Select File>Refresh to select the file.  That test class also displays this message.

I need to refresh the document and rebuild to get the servlet to run.

I was going to submit this to tech support but thought I would ask here first.  Hopefully it is an issue that can be easily resolved.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Might be related... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352550/meaning-of-java-lang-classcastexception-someclass-incompatible-with-someclass

Comment: If your ACL is changing frequently, consider using groups in the Domino Directory to manage permissions instead of modifying the ACL directly.