# org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory

Tags: java, xml, spring

I encounter below issues when i tried to start my application in WAS8.0.

[

```
12/5/13 16:01:53:633 GMT] 00000010 ContextLoader I org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[12/5/13 16:01:53:736 GMT] 00000010 XmlWebApplica I org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Dec 05 16:01:53 GMT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
[12/5/13 16:01:53:821 GMT] 00000010 XmlBeanDefini I org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [XXX.xml]
[12/5/13 16:01:53:858 GMT] 00000010 ContextLoader E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [XXX.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: <b>org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory</b>
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of java.lang.ClassCastException: someClass incompatible with someClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352550/meaning-of-java-lang-classcastexception-someclass-incompatible-with-someclass)  - Meaning, you have the same classes twice in your classpath. Those classes are now provided by the JRE, so be sure not to include any jar that contains them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you bring the latest version of Xerces into the classpath. `DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl` implements `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` as shown [here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/index.html).

And as @Augusto says, make sure you don't have multiple versions of Xerces either.

Comment: I also believe it should due to the collision of some jars, especially the XML parsing related jars, such as "Xerces", "pull-parser", so i exclude them in POM and also mark them as "optional", as result, those jars don't appear in the library of the WAR, however, when i use Maven Dependency plugin to analysis it, i found those dependencies have scope of "compile", so they may be still in server(local WAS8.0) when i publish them to server? a little confused.

Comment: Check both your war and the application server classpath.

Comment: I checked the classpath of my WAS v8.0, it's actually the default output folder of my source in workspace, so all the dependencies built by maven are available in WAS v8.0.