# error Jacob Library under lotus domino (unsatisfied linkError :jacob-1.17-x64(Library is already loaded in another classloader)

Tags: java, activex, xpages, lotus-domino, jacob

I have a webagent under lotus domino xpages that use jacob Library to execute macro under Microsoft Excel the agent work randomly and i have frequently an error.

The error came from this line in the code :
final ActiveXComponent excel = new ActiveXComponent("Excel.Application");

System OS :Win2008 server R2 x64 Domino Server 8.5.3 x86 can any one give me a help ?

[image]

Comment: Seems it does not like multiple class loaders, what is pure nature of XPages and you can't avoid it. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352550/meaning-of-java-lang-classcastexception-someclass-incompatible-with-someclass

Answer (score 1):

When you load libraries that have a native component (like the jacob library), you should make sure to load them once only. The agent runtime however loads every run using a separate class loader instance. You probably can have success with an XAgent and a application scope managed bean.

Running client type apps (like Excel) is never a good idea on a server